# Como escrever o seguinte código jQuery em JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando converter o seguinte código `jQuery` sem sucesso para `javascript` puro:

```js
$.each($("p"), function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  el.html(el.html() + " - " + i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
```

O que consegui fazer até agora foi:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
    var el = el;
    var teste = el.innerHTML += 
    teste " - " + i;
});
```

Comment: Já agora, ainda no JQuery, mais idiomático seria `$("p").each(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é necessário declarar as variáveis `el` e `teste`, apenas o trecho que concatena a variável `i` no `el.innterHTML` seria o suficiente para o código funcionar, na verdade elas que não estão permitindo o código funcionar corretamente:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
    el.innerHTML += " - " + i;
});
```

---

Utilizar o prototype do Array também não é necessário, visto que a variável `elements` já é iterável:

```
elements.forEach( (el, i) => {
  el.innerHTML += " - " + i;
});
```

---

O código final seria algo assim:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach( (el, i) => {
  el.innerHTML += " - " + i;
});
```

```html
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
```

Veja que aqui, nem mesmo declarei a variável `elements`, deixando um outro exemplo do que pode ser feito, efetuando o `forEach` diretamente no retorno da `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou muito bem, só tenho dúvida que li sobre forEach estar em desuso, que o melhor seria usar for.. in. Assim, saberia como ficaria o código com a forma mais recomendada?

Comment: Tem algumas outras formas, veja essa aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of